Al correr mi aplicación de react native me muestra error 404
Estaba haciendo un mantenimiento a mi aplicación de React Native y Expo, ya que Expo estaba en la versión 40 y ahora lo actualice a la versión 51, al finalizar la acutalización y probar que mi aplicación estuviera bien, intente ejecutarla en mi dispositivo y me mostro el siguiente error

Intente correrlo en un dispositivo virtual y dio el mismo resultado solo que en este caso en lugar de decir localhost, mostro la ip del dispositivo, por lo que no se que podria ser?
O en este caso se podria cambiar el localhost por el ip de mi PC, en caso que este sea el problema
